# Issue with SOQL Query to get approval comments

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to develop a component to show all comments for the approver and wrote a apex class for that to retrieve the comments of particular record. Still im failing to fetch records can any body help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

```
public with sharing class ApprovalHistoryController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getApprovalComments(Id recordId) {
        List<String> comments = new List<String>();
        
        // Query ProcessInstanceStep to retrieve comments
        for(ProcessInstanceStep step : [SELECT Comments
                                         FROM ProcessInstanceStep
                                         WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN 
                                             (SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstance 
                                              WHERE TargetObjectId = :recordId)]) {
           
            comments.add(step.Comments);
        }
        
        System.debug('Number of comments retrieved: ' + comments.size());
        return comments;
    }
}
```

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getApprovalComments from '@salesforce/apex/ApprovalHistoryController.getApprovalComments';

export default class ApprovalComments extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // Set this property with the record Id
    approvalComments = [];

    // Wire method to retrieve approval comments
    @wire(getApprovalComments, { recordId: '$recordId' })
    wiredApprovalComments({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.approvalComments = data;
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving approval comments', error);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Approval Comments">
        <template if:true={approvalComments}>
            <ul>
                <template for:each={approvalComments} for:item="comment">
                    <li key={comment}>{comment}</li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
        <template if:false={approvalComments}>
            <p>No approval comments found</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: May I please know if you are you getting an error or no approval comment is being fetched?

Answer (score 0):

As decribed in the documentation listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-wire-method.html).

> "To use @wire to call an Apex method, annotate the Apex method with
> @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)"

Your apex method has to be annotated with "(cacheable = true)" in order to @wire method in LWC.

```
public with sharing class ApprovalHistoryController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> getApprovalComments(Id recordId) {
        List<String> comments = new List<String>();
        
        // Query ProcessInstanceStep to retrieve comments
        for(ProcessInstanceStep step : [SELECT Comments
                                         FROM ProcessInstanceStep
                                         WHERE ProcessInstanceId IN 
                                             (SELECT Id FROM ProcessInstance 
                                              WHERE TargetObjectId = :recordId)]) {
           
            comments.add(step.Comments);
        }
        
        System.debug('Number of comments retrieved: ' + comments.size());
        return comments;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Prem, Thanks for ur response.
I think i might me wrong in query. while im trying to query with my submitted record id im unable to find the record in query. Please help me to sort the query.Thanks in advance.